# Does anyone seen this error oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: The endRequest call failed

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I have APEX running in tomcat. Recently after upgrading to latest ORDS 21.4.2 and APEX 21.1
when trying to access application I'm getting error. This seems to happening only in the morning after overnight inactivity. A first access of that URL result in that error, subsequent are fine.

`ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database.  This can occur if the database is unavailable, the maximum number of sessions has been reached or the pool is not correctly configured. The connection pool named: |apx100dev|pu| had the following error(s): Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: The endRequest call fail`

In the Tomcat logs I can see quite a big stack:

```
2022-03-30T10:31:12.752Z WARNING     :::got unchecked exception from user-defined connection labeling callback
2022-03-30T10:31:12.753Z SEVERE      <Zn1NIBM1in5tsu0bK4FrYQ> GET ords-apex-dev.apps.adpd-np.k8s.bgintdev.com /ords/<dbname>/ws/r/application/home?session=<sessionid> 503 ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database.  This can occur if the database is unavailable, the maximum number of sessions has been reached or the pool is not correctly configured. The connection pool named: |apx100dev|pu| had the following error(s): Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: The endRequest call failed 
ServiceUnavailableException [statusCode=503, logLevel=SEVERE, reasons=[ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database.  This can occur if the database is unavailable, the maximum number of sessions has been reached or the pool is not correctly configured. The connection pool named: |apx100dev|pu| had the following error(s): Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: The endRequest call failed ]]
    at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ServletResponseExceptionMapper.mapError(ServletResponseExceptionMapper.java:48)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorLogger.log(ErrorLogger.java:26)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:106)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.secure.ForceHttpsFilter.doFilter(ForceHttpsFilter.java:74)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.ForceAuthFilter.doFilter(ForceAuthFilter.java:44)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.Filters.filter(Filters.java:67)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPoint.service(EntryPoint.java:70)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.EntryPointServlet.service(EntryPointServlet.java:125)
    at oracle.dbtools.entrypoint.WebApplicationRequestEntryPoint.service(WebApplicationRequestEntryPoint.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.TargetNotAvailableException: ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database.  This can occur if the database is unavailable, the maximum number of sessions has been reached or the pool is not correctly configured. The connection pool named: |apx100dev|pu| had the following error(s): Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: The endRequest call failed 
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.db.PoolInjector.inject(PoolInjector.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.db.DatabaseURLMappingBase.addServices(DatabaseURLMappingBase.java:338)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.URLMappingBase.doFilter(URLMappingBase.java:75)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.db.DatabaseTenantMapping.dispatchSelf(DatabaseTenantMapping.java:193)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.db.DatabaseTenantMappingBase.doFilter(DatabaseTenantMappingBase.java:50)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.defaultpool.LegacyDatabaseTenantMapping.doFilter(LegacyDatabaseTenantMapping.java:46)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.tenant.TenantMappingDispatcher.dispatch(TenantMappingDispatcher.java:52)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.db.DatabaseTenantMappingBase.dispatchChild(DatabaseTenantMappingBase.java:151)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.db.DatabaseTenantMappingBase.doFilter(DatabaseTenantMappingBase.java:48)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.defaultpool.LegacyDatabaseTenantMapping.doFilter(LegacyDatabaseTenantMapping.java:46)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.defaultpool.LegacyDatabaseTenantMapping.doFilter(LegacyDatabaseTenantMapping.java:44)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.tenant.TenantMappingDispatcher.dispatch(TenantMappingDispatcher.java:52)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.tenant.TenantMappingFilter.doFilter(TenantMappingFilter.java:75)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.forwarding.ForwardingFailedFilter.doFilter(ForwardingFailedFilter.java:41)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.external.ExternalSessionFilter.doFilter(ExternalSessionFilter.java:59)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.rt.authentication.apex.ApexSessionQueryRewriteFilter.doFilter(ApexSessionQueryRewriteFilter.java:58)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.cors.CORSResponseFilter.doFilter(CORSResponseFilter.java:90)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.AbsoluteLocationFilter.doFilter(AbsoluteLocationFilter.java:65)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpResponseFilter.java:45)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.auth.external.ExternalAccessValidationFilter.doFilter(ExternalAccessValidationFilter.java:59)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.filters.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.dbtools.http.errors.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.ConnectionPoolConfigurationException: ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database.  This can occur if the database is unavailable, the maximum number of sessions has been reached or the pool is not correctly configured. The connection pool named: |apx100dev|pu| had the following error(s): Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: The endRequest call failed 
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.ConnectionPoolExceptions.from(ConnectionPoolExceptions.java:47)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.DataSourceConnection.getPooledConnection(DataSourceConnection.java:220)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.DataSourceConnection.getPooledConnection(DataSourceConnection.java:186)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.DataSourceConnection.getDefaultConnection(DataSourceConnection.java:144)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.DataSourceConnection.getConnection(DataSourceConnection.java:58)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.pools.DataSourceTargetImpl.getConnection(DataSourceTargetImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.config.db.SchemaConnectionFactoryBase.inject(SchemaConnectionFactoryBase.java:69)
    at oracle.dbtools.url.mapping.db.PoolInjector.inject(PoolInjector.java:58)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: The endRequest call failed
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:499)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:176)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1900)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.access$300(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:225)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$3.build(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:4050)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1823)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.ucp.PoolDataSourceDelegate.getConnection(PoolDataSourceDelegate.java:109)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.config.db.RefreshablePoolDataSource.getConnection(RefreshablePoolDataSource.java:109)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.ucp.PoolDataSourceDelegate.getConnection(PoolDataSourceDelegate.java:109)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.ucp.PoolDataSourceDelegate.getConnection(PoolDataSourceDelegate.java:96)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.jdbc.DataSourceConnection.getPooledConnection(DataSourceConnection.java:210)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: The endRequest call failed
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:379)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:347)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.returnConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:241)
    at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidateHelper(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:225)
    at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidate(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:166)
    at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:139)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:185)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:611)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:119)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1880)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.closeProxySession(T4CConnection.java:3512)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:2856)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:2742)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.closeConnectionSafely(PhysicalConnection.java:10964)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.drainOnInbandNotification(T4CConnection.java:7112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.checkAndDrain(PhysicalConnection.java:10846)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.endRequest(PhysicalConnection.java:10446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.endRequest(T4CConnection.java:9760)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.endRequest(PhysicalConnection.java:10459)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.returnConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:238)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureOpenAndConnected(SocketChannelImpl.java:215)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:527)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.write(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:467)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:361)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.writeDataToSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:206)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.writeDataToSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:151)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.flush(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:804)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:822)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:487)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:622)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:299)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOLOGOFF(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:74)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.closeProxySession(T4CConnection.java:3501)
    ... 99 more
```

I have been tweaking a config with pool limits and connection reuse but doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Is that the only error reported? It looks like maybe the session was terminated from the DB side through inactivity; can you look at the profile assigned to the connected user (probably the real one, not the proxy user) and see if IDLE_TIME or CONNECT_TIME might explain it. Or something at the network level could be killing it, possibly through inactivity. Can you test the connection before trying to use (or close) it?

Comment: Right before I can see:
`2022-03-30T10:31:12.752Z WARNING     :::got unchecked exception from user-defined connection labeling callback`
The profiles using standard DEFAULT.